# Multiple service instances using Hangfire (shared tasks/objects), is it possible?

Tags: hangfire, resiliency

I need to run multiple instances of the same service, with the same database, for redundancy reason.

I found some question about "Hangfire multiple instances" but for a differenct purpose then mine: usually about running multiple instances for different tasks on the same database, or similar to this.

I need to know if there are problems of concurrency when 2 or more instances of Hangfire use the same Database (we want to use MongoDB) and if this is the solution to make the service resilient.
The goal is to have instance that take care of all the jobs when another instance goes down.

Any suggestion wellcome for covering this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our environment, we have a replica set used by about 10 Hangfire servers. If there are multiple Hangfire servers servicing the same queue, it means they will share the load and whichever Hangfire server checks the queue first, picks up the job and continues. If you remove all but 1 server, the jobs will continue (as long as there are enough workers otherwise they will remain queued until a worker is available).

To answer your question, yes, you can have 2 or more Hangfire servers using the same MongoDB. MongoDB provides multi-threading support so its safe to have various servers accessing the same database backend. If you have two servers, both will be active and if one instance goes off line, other instance (based on queues) will continue to process the jobs in queue.

Keep in mind, Hangfire servers processes the jobs in Specific Queues. If both servers are part of the same queue then you are load balancing the jobs among the two servers. If they are part of different queues, then you read about that scenario where each Hangfire instance processes different jobs (because they are part of different queues).

[Read about configuring Job Queues here](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/configuring-queues.html)